# Error while insert dataframe to Sql-server DB using to_sql function in python

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sql-insert, pandas-to-sql

I am trying to insert pandas dataframe df into SQL Server DB using dataframe.to_sql function. But i getting below error:

**Source code:**

```
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy
import urllib

df  #sample dataframe
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=GIRSQL.GIRCAPITAL.com;DATABASE=Tableau;UID=SQL_User;PWD=pass")
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
engine.connect()
df.to_sql(name='[Tableau].[dbo].[Test table]',con=engine, index=False, 
if_exists='append')
```

**Error:**

> File "C:\Users\Arvinth\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 470, in do_execute
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
>
> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'INTEGER'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)") [SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE [[Tableau].[dbo].[Test table]] (\n\t[A] INTEGER NULL, \n\t[B] INTEGER NULL, \n\t[C] INTEGER NULL\n)\n\n']

Sample dataframe:

```
    A  B  C
 0  0  0  0
 1  1  1  1
 2  2  2  2
 3  3  3  3
 4  4  4  4
 5  5  5  5
 6  6  6  6
 7  7  7  7
```

Can anyone please help solve the issue.

Comment: This is not necessary *[Tableau].[dbo].* as you are connecting to *Tableau* and default schema is *dbo*. Simply pass table name: `df.to_sql(name='Test table',con=engine, index=False, 
if_exists='append')`

Comment: Its working fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As commented, you referenced the database name and `dbo` schema for table *name* arg in pandas' `to_sql` call for *'[Tableau].[dbo].[Test table]'* and bracketed the names, rendering an error in the sqlAlchemy engine's `CREATE TABLE` SQL call. Since the current connection *is* the referenced database and the default schema is `dbo`, both qualifiers in name are not needed: *<s>`'[Tableau].[dbo].</s>'*

Hence, in `df.to_sql`, simply reference the table name without bracket escaping:

```
df.to_sql(name='Test table', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

which will create the needed table  in the default `dbo` schema of the connected `Tableau` database:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Test table] (
    [A] INTEGER NULL,
    [B] INTEGER NULL, 
    [C] INTEGER NULL
);
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can refer the table in `to_sql()`:

```
df.to_sql('test_table',con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

Comment: this is also mentioned in the accepted answer. Only add new answers if you have another solution to the same problem.